# Serverless - Get the created cloudfront resource URL and use it as environment variables

Tags: javascript, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, serverless

I am working with serverless.js, I am creating a CloudFront distribution with serverless cloudformation, and in the application code, I want to use the generated CloudFront URL.
Therefore I want to set the environment variable in serverless.yml to the dynamic CloudFront URL which will be generated when creating the resource. Is there any way that I can achieve a solution to the above-mentioned problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a CloudFront Distribution custom resource in your `serverless.yml`, you can reference it into an environment variable.

```yaml
provider:
  ...
  environment:
    FRONTEND_URL: !Join ['', ['https://', !GetAtt FrontendDistribution.DomainName]]

resources:
  Resources:
    FrontendDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      ...
```